# Stopping Pandas from writing non-ASCII characters that aren't in the source

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas

Using Pandas, I'm pulling a CSV from a resource and writing it to a new CSV for further processing. Pandas seems to be writing non-ASCII characters to the first header column, these are not present in the source CSV. How can I make Pandas ignore those special characters (they appear to not change) when Pandas writes the CSV?

"Computer Name" must have the special characters(\xef\xbb\xbf) included, or nothing is written in the CSV for that column. I found the characters being the problem when I had Pandas download the whole CSV to a file, but the special characters are not present when I have the readout printed to the terminal.

```
pandasdata = pandas.read_csv(r'\\mydrive\resource.csv')
header = ["IP Address", "\xef\xbb\xbfComputer Name", "OS"]
pandasdata.to_csv('localresources.csv', columns = header)
```

As requested, here are the results from querying what columns were in the CSV:

```
print(pandasdata.columns.tolist())
```

['\xef\xbb\xbfComputer Name', 'OS', 'Location', 'Serial', 'DeskID' 'IP Address']

Comment: what does `pandasdata.columns.tolist()` show? also are you sure it's not unicode BOM in your file? try `pandasdata = pandas.read_csv(r'\\mydrive\resource.csv', encoding='utf-8')` or `pandasdata = pandas.read_csv(r'\\mydrive\resource.csv', encoding='utf-16')`

Comment: @EdChum UTF-8 errors with ascii codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128). 

UTF-16 errors with  CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python' .

For your first suggestion, where am I'm supposed to place that?

Comment: edit your question with the output from `print(pandasdata.columns.tolist())` this will show you whether your columns have some kind of duff values, you can then override the names of the columns if you wish by doing `df.columns = ["IP Address", "Computer Name", "OS"]` to get rid of the strange symbols

Comment: @EdChum I've edited the question to include the tolist() results. I found the answer on a separate question that related to changing just one field after looking up the method you proposed to research it further. Thanks!

Comment: it seems to me that \xef\xbb\xbf is utf-8 BOM:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding I don't know what else is wrong with your data wrt to your earlier remark unless you include a link to the original data

Answer (score 0):

It seems that renaming the column itself worked for me rather than telling Pandas to ignore the special characters. Below is the code I used to after reading the CSV. After it got renamed, I included the new name to the header list. It's unknown why Pandas was writing the special characters, when they were not part of the source CSV.

```
df.rename(columns = {'\xef\xbb\xbfComputer Name':'Computer Name'}, inplace = True
```